# What is the internal of `next_permutation()` function in c++

Tags: c++, function, permutation

Recently I solved a problem of permutation. Then I searched for library function for solve a the problem. I found `next_permutation` function. Using the function I Solved the problem. I searched a lot to find out the internal of the function but I did not find good sources.

```
 vector<vector<int>> permute(vector<int>& nums) {
        sort(nums.begin(), nums.end());
        vector<vector<int>>v;
        do{
            v.push_back(nums);
        }while(next_permutation(nums.begin(), nums.end()));
        return v;
    }
```

I want to know about the internal of the function. If anyone know about it , please share a code for the function.

Comment: [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) has "Possible implementation" section. You can look up actual different implementations of standard library, but these will be convoluted and hard to read.

Comment: Many implementations of the standard library are freely available to view.  If you want to know how _your_ `std::next_permutation` is written, first find out which standard library you are using.

Comment: [OT]: No need of `vv`, `v.push_back(nums);` would do the job.

Comment: And it is generally faster to do the work in the loop instead of returning a (potential huge) vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the implementation from [`libstdc++`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_algo.h#L2880-L2916) (same as in [SGI STL](https://github.com/karottc/sgi-stl/blob/master/stl_algo.h#L2876-L2906)) simplified and cleaned up a little bit for readability:

```
template<typename BidirectionalIterator>
bool next_permutation(BidirectionalIterator first, BidirectionalIterator last)
{
    if (first == last)
        return false;
    BidirectionalIterator i = first;
    ++i;
    if (i == last)
        return false;
    i = last;
    --i;

    for(;;)
    {
        BidirectionalIterator ii = i;
        --i;
        if (*i < *ii)
        {
            BidirectionalIterator j = last;
            while (!(*i < *--j)) {}
            std::swap(*i, *j);
            std::reverse(ii, last);
            return true;
        }
        if (i == __first)
        {
            std::reverse(first, last);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This is a well-known algorithm ("Algorithm L"), see Sec. 7.2.1.2 *Generating all permutations* in *The art of computer programming. [Vol. 4A: Combinatorial algorithms](http://www.cs.utsa.edu/%7Ewagner/knuth/fasc2b.pdf), Part 1* by D.E.Knuth.

Idea of the algorithm: for the current permutation, find the longest decreasing subsequence on the right, `{...ap ≤ ai > aj > ... > ak}`, find the next front element `af > ap` with the largest possible `f` in the range `[i, k]`, swap `af` and `ap`, and then put the remaining elements in the ascending order, i.e. reverse the subsequence `{ai...ap...ak}`.